# Stop router-link until confirm return

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vue-router

I'm building a food-delivery website. I need to tell the user that, when he clicks on the component which redirects him in another page via vuejs2 router-link, his shopping cart will be deleted.
At the moment I have this:

```
<RestaurantBox
              v-for="(restaurant, index) in activeRestaurants"
              :key="`restaurant${index}`"
              :restaurant="restaurant"
              @click.native="confirmChange"  
            />
```

with the given function:

```
confirmChange() {
            if (!confirm('Attenzione! Se cambi ristorante perderai quello che hai messo nel carrello.')) {
              location.href = '/restaurants/' + this.activeType.slug;
            }  
            
      }
```

This kinda works: if I click cancel, the statement in the if does what it should do, but when I click on the component it changes the url via router-link before the confirm(), so it's basically useless.
Any ideas?

Comment: I don't see the router link code here but what I understood is you want to do some action before the user actually redirects so using the router link is not a good idea here. if you want to use vue router way so better to call router.push once user accepts the message(similar to what you already tried). https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/navigation.html#navigate-to-a-different-location

Comment: In your question you speak about ```router-link```, I could not see any ```router-link``` in your codes. If you change the ```url``` with ```location.href```, then it is not the way that "vue router" works. See [documentation](https://v3.router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/navigation.html) to change the route correctly.

Comment: Make a button and do the verifications inside of it. Don't use `location.href` in a SPA context, because it nukes the whole thing.